# How to import a video file with multiple tracks?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio, linux

I want to import some OBS videos into Blender and they have multiple audio tracks, but Blender shows only one audio track

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences you can set the number of channels to be used in Blender:
[image]

But you can't get them separated into individual strips. So, you'll need to use some other software and save each channel as separate files and import them as such.

If you set the audio strips to mono, the Pan option gets activated, and you can pan each strip into the speaker you want to hear it from.

[image]

Unfortunately, the values to pan to are super unintuitive for anything else than Stereo.

```
pan_stereo = {
    'LEFT': - 1.0, 
    'CENTER': 0,
    'RIGHT': 1.0,
}
pan_surround4 = {
    'FRONTLEFT': - 0.5, 
    'FRONTCENTER': 0.0, 
    'FRONTRIGHT': 0.5,
    'SIDELEFT': -1.5,
    'SIDERIGHT': 1.5,
}
pan_surround51 = {
    'FRONTLEFT': - 0.33335, 
    'FRONTCENTER': 0.0, 
    'FRONTRIGHT': 0.33335,
    'SIDELEFT': -1.2225,
    'SIDERIGHT': 1.2225,
}
pan_surround71 = {
    'FRONTLEFT': - 0.33335, 
    'FRONTCENTER': 0.0, 
    'FRONTRIGHT': 0.33335,
    'SIDELEFT': -1.2225,
    'SIDERIGHT': 1.2225,
    'REARLEFT': -1.66667,
    'REARRIGHT': 1.66667,
}
```

Links to my failed attempts to improve the channel panning UI:
https://archive.blender.org/developer/D11933
https://archive.blender.org/developer/differential/0012/0012114/index.html